# Display Selected Value For Slider InAppSettings Kit

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, inappsettingskit

I am using InAppSettingsKit and I have a slider. I want to display the closest integer in the heading on the row above. I am not really concerned about the settings from the iphone settings but the one from within my app

[image: AnnAppSettingsKit Slider]

Here is my Root.InApp.Plist

[image: Root.InApp.Plist]

What I have done is define a notification which works when the slider is moved

```
#pragma mark kIASKAppSettingChanged notification
- (void)settingDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification {
if ([notification.object isEqual:kGameReward]) {
    }
}
```

I just do not know how to find and access the cell in the tableview to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the value for the `answers` key:

```
NSInteger value = round([notification.userInfo[@"gamereward"] doubleValue]);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:value forKey:@"answers"]
```

IASK automatically updates the UI when the underlying userDefaults are updated.